# Threading and Looping in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multithreading

I am looking for a way to for my threads to iterate through an array of email addresses without stepping on each others toes and changing the variables (I can't use mutex). I found some information on using  "thread local variables" but can't seem to get that to work. Below is an example of my problem (this is just a small chuck of the code).

```
(1..(threads).map { |thread_count|

  Thread.new do

    (1..(messages).each do |message_count|

    email = recipients_array[recipient_count].join(", ") 

    if (recipient_count != ( recipients_array.length - 1 ))
      recipient_count += 1
    else
      recipient_count = 0
    end
```

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm writing script that utilize multithreading in JRuby for the purpose of sending emails. I tell the script how many threads I want to send and how many messages per thread I am going to send. I pass in a text file of recipient addresses which I load into an array. I then want to iterate through the array so that:

- Thread 1, Message 1 will go to email 1
- Thread 2, Message 1 will go to email 1
- Thread 1, Message 2 will go to email 2
- Thread 2, Message 2 will go to email 2

and so on... It starts off fine but If I'm setting up to do 5 threads x 5 messages:

- Threads 1 through 5, Message 1 will go to email 1
- Thread 1, Message 2 will go to email 6

because they are all accessing recipient_count variable and incrementing it +1.

Looking for some advice on how to set this up better.

Comment: what is `recipient_count`? where is it intialized? it seems you might have a race condition here...

Comment: This smells of premature optimization. How many email do you need to send per second? Have you tested to see if a single-thread can stay ahead of your needs?

Comment: @theTinMan, Has to be multithreaded, unfortunately

Comment: @UriAgassi Yes, exactly. recipient_count is initialized at the beginning of the code. The problem is all threads are accessing this variable and changing it, so instead of going from 1 to 2 to 3 it goes from 1 to 5 to 10; it's not iterating through the array like I'd like... I'm looking for a way for them each to access the variable and iterate through the array

Answer (score 0):

Usually I utilize ruby multithreading this way:

```
require 'thread'

count  = 4
result = []

mutex  = Mutex.new
queue  = Queue.new

# fill the queue
(0..100).each do |i|
  queue << i
end

(0..count).map do
  begin
    loop do
      item = queue.pop(true)
      item = do_something_with_it(item)

      mutex.synchronize do
        result << item
      end
    end
  rescue ThreadError
    Thread.exit
  end
end.each(&:join)

# process results
```

Comment: Right and this is great and very similar to hose my code is... the issue I have is that I don't know how to iterate through the array when all threads are going at once.

Comment: i can't use mutex and even if i did, i would still have this issue with my variables.

Answer (score 0):

You said this script is called with the `threads`, `messages` and `recipient_array` as arguments. I'm not sure what form the individual entries in `recipients_array` take or what the `Array#join` is for, nor why you reset `recipient_count` to 0 when it has reached the last index of `recipients_array`. I assume there is some missing code. But, how about this.

```
emails_handled = []
(0..threads - 1).map do |i|
  Thread.new do
    (i..messages * threads - 1).step(threads) do |n|
      email = recipients_array[n].join(", ")
      emails_handled[n] = 1
      # ... do stuff with your email
    end
  end
end
```

- Each thread has the same step and same endpoint, but a different starting point, so they don't clash. It's not optimal, but I'm pretty new to threads myself.
- When you want to get `recipient_count`, you can call `emails_handled.compact.reduce(:+)`. I wasn't sure if you needed `recipient_count` for anything other than the `recipients_array[]` lookup - if not, you can dump `emails_handled` entirely.